# Which is more: dissociated ions in water or undissociated?

Tags: physical-chemistry

While studying equilibrium we get to know that there are $1*10^{-7} \ce{~~OH-}$ and $\ce{H+}$ ions in pure water. However, I think there are more undissociated molecules.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/dissociation-of-water-into-h-and-oh-does-the-law-of-mass-action-hold-at-nanos

Comment: Wait.... What *exactly* are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

> […] there are $1\cdot10^{-7}\ \ce{OH-}$ […] ions

Are you sure that this is an absolute number or rather a concentration in $\mathrm{\frac{mol}{L}}$? IN the latter case, what would be the concentration of undiscociated $\ce{H2O}$ molecules in 1 liter of water?